# How to scale div's contents with the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a parent div that contains an image with a bunch of "holes" in it. I have a child div for each hole that defines the exact size of those holes. In the holes, I have text that I've set to position:absolute so that they fit exactly in the holes. However, when I resize the parent div, the contents don't scale at all and they stay the same size. They're also not inside the holes anymore.

Comment: What values are you using for positioning (e.g. top, left, etc.) and what type of size for your text?

Comment: Are you using pixels to set width/position or percentages? Also, more code would be helpful

Comment: I'm using pixels to set the width and height of the child divs. I'm also using transform/translate to move the child divs into the holes

Answer (score 2):

User '%' as a unit instead of pixel

```
<div id="ParentDiv">
    <img src="../610614-spring-forest.jpg">
    <div class="hole1">Tree1</div>
</div>

#ParentDiv{
        max-width:900px;
        position: relative;
    }
    img{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .hole1{
        position: absolute;
        left:2.75%;
        top:23.87%;
    }
```

You can use Viewport Hieght or Viewport Width unit for that case. Below is the example how you could use.

```
#ParentDiv{
        max-width:100vw;
        max-height:100vh;
        position: relative;
    }
    img{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .hole1{
        position: absolute;
        /*left:2.75%;
        top:23.87%;*/
        left:2.75vw;
        top:23.87vh;
    }
```

Try to use similar, hope you will get the desired result.

Comment: I can use % to define where the hole goes but how do i define how big it is. If i increase the size of the parent div, the holes increase in size too. Also, the size of the parent div depends on the size of the window so I have to use like 100% instead of pixels

Comment: For that case we can use View port height or View port width unit, i.e max-width:100vw; vw = viewport width, vh = viewport height, Use it instead of pixel and of percentage. 100Vw = 100% width , ie whole visible screen width.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CSS property called `transform` instead of directly changing the size.

When you need to set the size of the image:

```
// this is the container the image and its text is in
imageContainer = document.getElementById('myDiv');
// original size of image
origX = 400;
origY = 300;
// size you need it to change to
newX = 800;
newY = 600;
/*
Tells CSS to stretch from the top-left edge of the object, so it won't stretch off the left side of the screen
Best way to change value would be percentages
Value of '0 0' sets origin to top-left
Value of '100% 100%' sets origin to bottom-right
*/
imageContainer.style.transformOrigin = '0 0';
//the following is just one string, broken into multiple lines for easy explanation
// tells CSS that the transform type is scale
imageContainer.style.transform = 'scale(' +
    // tells CSS how many times normal size to widen image. in this case evaluates to 2, since 800/400 is 2, making image 2x wider
    (newX / origX) + ',' +
    // tells CSS how many times normal size to heighten image. in this case evaluates to 2, since 600/300 is 2, making image 2x taller
    (newY / origY) + ')';
```

Assuming you have no major performance-sapping functions, this will work great. It's just a little slow if you have loads of stuff going on.

Uncommented:

```
imageContainer = document.getElementById('myDiv');
origX = 400;
origY = 300;
newX = 800;
newY = 600;
imageContainer.style.transformOrigin = '0 0';
imageContainer.style.transform = 'scale(' + (newX / origX) + ',' (newY / origY) + ')';
```